# Внедрение JS-сценария, изменение исходного кода страницы.

Tags: html, php, внедрение, javascript

Здравствуйте!
Есть ли способ внедрения JavaScript-сценария в исходный код чужой страницы?
Например, при переходе на чужой сайт, в его исходный код внедряется Javascript-код, заполняющий форму автоматически. Или это дело можно реализовать как-то по-другому, например, через GET-запрос?

---

Нужно выполнять код именно локально, потому что внедрить его сервер - это уже тема взлома.

Answer (score 1):

В адресной строке

```
javascript: alert("Работает")
```

Comment: Да именно об этом я и написал )

Comment: А выражение такого вида : 
>javascript: var op = document.getElementById("FirstName"); op.value="123" 

Не работает....

Comment: Ну, так что?

Comment: Глупый огнелис эту плюху заблокировал? e ytuj ntgthm njkmrj bp dt,-rjycjkb crhbgns bcgjkyz.ncz :'(

Answer (score 0):

Можно в командную строку вставлять JS код и исполнять. Лучше опишите задачу которую нужно сделать.

Comment: Задача: при переходе на опр.сайт, заполнять форму, но все время разными значениями. А командная строка, это, как я понимаю, консоль в браузере Google Chrome ?

Comment: Нет командная строка, это то где url адрес сайта

Comment: Нет, "командная строка", как неправильно выразился @Сергей Степанов, это просто адресная строка браузера

Comment: А, благодарю! Большое спасибо. Не могли бы вы привести пример, пожалуйтса =)